# Is there a python function to convert ordinal number to word

Tags: python

I have a Address column in panda dataframe. I need to convert ordinal numbers like 1st to first, 2nd to second and so on in python. I tried searching a solution but no success.

My data frame looks like this:-

````
print(newdf) :- 
Address 
0 2 fairgreen lane bolton callan 
1 2 leix rd cabra dublin 7 
2 7 sraid na mara 1st sea rd strandhill rd 

Suppose the 3rd record has 1st sea road, it should be converted to first sea road. I am not sure how to pass the data frame column in the argument.

```python
The below code converts number to word. 
 num2words(42, to='ordinal') 'forty-second'  num2words(42, to='cardinal') 'forty-two'
````

Comment: it looks like you have answered your own question. [`num2words`](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words) does exactly that...

Comment: Actually I want to convert 1st to first and 2nd to second and so on. num2words is taking only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract your number from your string (i.e. extract `42` from `42nd`) and then use `num2words` with `ordinal=True`:

```
import re
from num2words import num2words

ordinalAsNumber = "42nd"
number = re.search('\d+', ordinalAsNumber)

ordinalAsString = num2words(number[0], ordinal=True)

print( ordinalAsString ) # forty-second
```

You can extract all ordinals from a string like this:

```
text = "Text with several ordinals such as 42nd, 31st, and 5th as well as plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3."
numbers = re.findall('(\d+)[st|nd|rd|th]', text)

for n in numbers:
     ordinalAsString = num2words(n, ordinal=True)
     print( ordinalAsString )
```

Output:

```
forty-second
thirty-first
fifth
```

You can do replacements with `re.sub()`:

```
text = "Text with several ordinals such as 42nd, 31st, and 5th as well as plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3."
numbers = re.findall('(\d+)[st|nd|rd|th]', text)

newText = text
for n in numbers:
     ordinalAsString = num2words(n, ordinal=True)
     newText=re.sub(r"\d+[st|nd|rd|th]", ordinalAsString, text, 1)

print ( text )
print( newText )
```

Output:

```
# Text with several ordinals such as 42nd, 31st, and 5th as well as plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3.
# Text with several ordinals such as forty-secondd, thirty-firstt, and fifthh as well as plain numbers such as 1, 2, 3.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. It is working this way, But I have a dataframe column containing address and I need to pass this as argument.  My data frame looks like this:-  print(newdf) :-  
                                                Address
0                         2 fairgreen lane bolton callan
1                               2 leix rd cabra dublin 7
2         7 sraid na mara 1st sea rd strandhill rd
Suppose the 3rd record has 1st sea road, it should be converted to first sea road. I am not getting how to pass he dataframe column.

Comment: You can do replacements with `re.sub()`, I added an example to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good package that you can pip install into your project that will convert ordinal numbers to words https://pypi.org/project/num2words/ the documentation here gives lots of good info on how to use it.